# ¿Cómo añadir dos parámetros en la creación de una cookie?

Tags: php

No sé cómo añadir dos parámetros, usuario y contraseña, ¿qué falta añadirle?

```php
// ME GUSTARÍA AÑADIR USUARIO PERO TAMBIÉN CONTRASEÑA
setcookie("user", '$usuario', time() + 86400);
```

Comment: La documentación indica *no almacenar información sensible*: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php#refsect1-function.setcookie-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Como te indican en los comentarios, no deberias de guardar información sensible en los comentarios puesto que las cookies se almacenan en el ordenador de cliente, por lo cual cualquier persona con acceso a dicho ordenador podría ver la cookie y robar el nombre de usuario y contraseña.

Ahora bien, si aún así decides seguir adelante o necesitas la misma solución para otro tipo de datos, puedes hacer lo siguiente.

Puedes guardar ambos datos en un mismo string, pero separandolos con un caracter en conconcreto, para luego poder separar el string por dicho caracter.

Por ejemplo:

```
$dato1 = "hola";
$dato2 = "adios";

//Guardamos la cookie con ambos datos, separados por |
$string = $dato1.'|'.$dato2; //En este punto $string = "hola|adios"
setcookie("datos", '$string', time() + 86400);
```

Más adelante cuando quieras obtener los datos, puedes usar cualquiera de las funciones que te permiten dividir strings, como por ejemplo explode, la cual te genera un array, diviendo el string por el caracter que tu le indiques.

```
$datos_cookie = $_COOKIE["datos"];
//Esto nos separa el string por | creando un array
$array_datos_cookie = explode("|", $datos_cookie);
//En este punto tendriamos un array, con dos posiciones ( 0 y 1 ). En la posición 0 tendriamos el valor "hola" y en la posicion 1 el valor "adios"
Array (
    [0] => "hola"
    [1] => "adios"
)
```